# I want to make a command help but the console code gives an error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Faced a problem, the code is written correctly, as I think, but the console gives errors. What is the problem?

My code

````
#help
@client.command( pass_context = True )

async def help(ctx):
 
    emb = discord.Embed( title = 'Command Reference!', colour = 0x2f3136 )
    
    emb.add_field(name = 'Bot prefix:', value='```>```', inline=True) 
    emb.add_field( name = 'Personnel teams', value='')    
    emb.add_field(name = 'Blocking a user', value='```>ban 1с/н/м Reason```', inline=True)

    await ctx.send( embed = emb, delete_after=60.0 )
````

Error:

```
Ignoring exception in command help:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vlad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\vlad\Desktop\embed.py", line 147, in help
    await ctx.send( embed = emb, delete_after=60.0 )
  File "C:\Users\vlad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1065, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, content, tts=tts, embed=embed,
  File "C:\Users\vlad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 254, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.fields.0.value: This field is required

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vlad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\vlad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vlad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.fields.0.value: This field is required
```

I tried to change the parameters `async def help(ctx):` but it didn't lead to anything

Comment: You can't have an empty value field.

Comment: Is this the whole mistake?

Comment: yes... `In embed.fields.0.value: This field is required`

Answer (score 1):

The Mistake You Have Is In Line `emb.add_field( name = 'Personnel teams', value='')`
You Can't Have An Empty Field!

Answer (score 1):

Just change:

```
emb.add_field( name = 'Personnel teams', value='')
```

To:

```
emb.add_field( name = 'Personnel teams', value='** **')
```

The issue is that the field is empty.
Also if you haven't already, At the start of the code add `help_command=None` to your client object. Like this:

```
client = commands.Bot(help_command=None)
```

Comment: by using `** **` will eliminate the error but still leave the field empty